# Error in listview name sensors android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-sensors

I'm trying to display only the name of sensors in my listview.. In the log i can do it but in my listview not:

```
 mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    for(Sensor s : deviceSensors) {
        Log.d("SENSORS", s.getName());
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sensor>(this,
                R.layout.customlistview, deviceSensors);
    }
```

In this way i can display the names in the log my in the listview appears every information about sensors and not only the name. If i try in this way:

```
 mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    for(Sensor s : deviceSensors) {
        Log.d("SENSORS", s.getName());
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sensor>(this,
                R.layout.customlistview, s.getName()));
    }
```

It gets me error in listview: `The constructor ArrayAdapter<Sensor>(SensorsActivity, int, String) is undefined` how can i solve?

Comment: you want the names\ in the list?

Comment: yes only the names of sensors..possibly, also the vendor. i think is `s.getVendor()`.. but i don't know how..

Comment: use a custom adapter if you want both vendor and name. for displaying names have arraylist. add the names to the list in for loop. outside for loop   `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item1,namesList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter)`;

Comment: doesn't work..i get error in `s`.. can you show me how with the code i post above?

Comment: waht is the error post the updated code and error

Comment: I'm not with pc now..but anyway same as my first post but outside for loop i wrote your custom adapter  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String(this,R.layout.customlistview, s.getName()); listView.setAdapter(adapter);  but not works

Comment: not work meanining you get exception. post the code and the specify whats wrong or else how will i know what's wrong. that is not a custom adapter. for a custom adapter you need to have a custom class that extends `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` override getview inflate custom layout and return the view in getview.

Comment: Ok, but i can't understand why in the log works :(

Comment: the logs works but you are using adapter in for loop which is not needed and your adapter constructor is wrong. try this 
    `ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayL:ist<String>();
    for(Sensor s : deviceSensors) {
            Log.d("SENSORS", s.getName());
            names.add(s.getName().toString());
    
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item1,aa);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter)`

Comment: try the above code in the comment . you had this `R.layout.customlistview` replace that by `android.R.layout.simple_list_item1` and you are supposed to have just one adapter. add the items to your list and if it does not work let me know

Comment: instead of `aa` use `names` coz that is the arraylist name in the code posted in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log works because you're printing the name of every single sensor in it. Adapters just work different. You need one `Adapter` for the whole list view. Then, when you want to show more then just one text, e.g. sensor name and vendor, you must also override the `getView()` method in the Adapter. In there you handle all the settings for one line in the list view.

Lets start with the simple way of just the sensor name in each line of the list view:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.customlistview));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

for(Sensor s : deviceSensors) {
    Log.d("SENSORS", s.getName());
    adapter.add(s.getName());
}
```

Your `R.layout.customlistview` must contain a single `TextView` that is used to show the given string (sensor name).

Comment: Well, with this one solution works..but it shows only one sensor.. Is it correct?

Comment: sorry, i've seen just now that there are all sensors but the list shows only the first item.. i think the cause is the list height..